# No quiere cargar una funcion js en específico en el navegador Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que que pasa es que: solo en el navegador Internet Explorer no carga una función que en otros navegadores si, no se si sea por el modo de mandar llamarlo o el contenido de la función. Cabe mencionar que el html lo tengo en la carpeta principal y el archivo.js esta en el mismo directorio pero en una carpeta llamada js. Adjunto mi codigo para que sea mas facil la comprension.

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="menu"></div><!--por medio de una función cargo el menú-->

 <script
  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/EN_ES.js" type="text/javascript"></script> <!--Este es el archivo.js-->

  <script type="text/JavaScript"> 
 //esta función carga el menu en el div con el id="menu"
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").load("html/menu.html");
     });
     </script>
</body>
</html>
```

El menu tiene el siguiente código: menu.html el cual tiene una opción con una etiqueta `<p onclick="myEspañol()"> spanish</p>` con la que se manda llamar la función.

```
 <!--Menu-->
<div class=" example5">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar5">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img style="width: 110px;" src="https://picsum.photos/1680/945/?random" alt="Dispute Bills">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar5" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
          <li class="active"><a href="#home" class="bu" id="1" data-toggle="tab"><div id="home"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home</div></a></li>
          <li><a href="#company" class="bu" id="2" data-toggle="tab"> <div id="company"><img class="icon icons8-Fábrica" width="19" height="19" src="img/iconfab.png" style="padding-bottom:3px;"> Company</div></a></li>

     <li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><div id="Capabilities"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span> Capabilities</div></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
     <li><a href="#Engineering" class="bu" id="3" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Ing">Engineering</div></a></li>
     <li><a href="#Foundry" id="4" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Fundicion">Foundry</div></a></li>
     <li><a href="#Machining" id="5" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Maquinado">Machining</div></a></li>
     <li><a href="#Logistics" id="6" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Logistica">Logistics</div></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
   <li><a href="#Product" id="7" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Productos"><img class="icon icons8-Producto" width="16" height="16" style="padding-bottom:3px;" src="img/iconprod.png"> Products</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="#Quality" id="8" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Calidad"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> Quality Control</div></a></li>
   <li><a href="#Contact" id="10" class="bu" data-toggle="tab"><div id="Contacto"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span> Contact</div></a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">

<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><div id="Idioma"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span> Language <span class="caret"></span></div></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
 <div id="TipoIdioma"><li><p class="bu" onclick="myEspañol()" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left:5%;" id="spa">Spanish</p></li></div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div style = "padding:2px;  background-color:#F8F9F9;"></div>
  </nav>

</div>
<!--Menu-->
```

El archivo.js el es siguiente:

```
function myEspañol() {
    //Menu
    document.getElementById("home").innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>' + ' Home';
    document.getElementById("company").innerHTML = '<img class="icon icons8-Fábrica" width="19" height="19" src="img/iconfab.png" style="padding-bottom:3px;">'+' Empresa';
    document.getElementById("Capabilities").innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-compressed"></span>' + ' Capacidades';
    document.getElementById("Ing").innerHTML = 'Ingenieria';
    document.getElementById("Fundicion").innerHTML = 'Fundicion';
    document.getElementById("Maquinado").innerHTML = 'Maquinado';
    document.getElementById("Logistica").innerHTML = 'Logistica';
    document.getElementById("Productos").innerHTML = '<img class="icon icons8-Producto" width="16" height="16" style="padding-bottom:3px;" src="img/iconprod.png">' + ' Productos';
    document.getElementById("Calidad").innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>' + ' Control de Calidad';
    document.getElementById("Contacto").innerHTML = '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span>' + ' Contacto';
    document.getElementById("Idioma").innerHTML ='<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span>' + ' Idioma ' + '<span class="caret"></span>';
    document.getElementById("TipoIdioma").innerHTML = '<li><p class="bu" onclick="resetbody()" style="cursor: pointer; padding-left:5%;" id="spa">Ingles</p></li>';
}
```

Comment: cambia el nombre de myEspañol a myEspanol, es una maña practica usar esos caracteres para palabras reservadas.

Comment: apoyando lo que dice @LucianoMontañez si no tienes el encoding en el header puede que te falle por eso!

Answer (score 0):

intenta poner esta etiqueta en tu html

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9"/>
```

algo que te podria ayudar es que en IE8 e IE9 no se puede llamar de la misma forma a una variable como una id o como un name. Ni aunque este en un comentario

ejemplo:

Queria apuntar que en mi caso no pude llamarle inter a una id (id="inter") porque habia una linea en un comentario:

```
<!--<input type="text" size="8" name="inter" value="00:00:00.00 ">-->
```